# I get an error: Access violation reading location when I try to create a new "Image" class

Tags: c++, pointers, file-io, constructor

I am trying to read from a file using this method in my main.  I have data that I want to extract from it to create a new Image object.  Not too sure how to fix it at this point.

```
Image readFile(string fileName) {
ifstream file;
file.open(fileName);
int rowCount;
int column;
if(file.is_open()){

        file >> rowCount;
        file >> column;

}
int **row = new int*[rowCount];
Image i(**row, column); //The debugger stops here and gives the error!!!!!!!!
file.close();
return i;
```

}

This is my constructor for the Image object

```
Image::Image(int R = 0, int C = 0) {
if(R < 1 || C < 1) {
    *row = new int[10];
    column = new int[10];
} else {
*row = new int[R];
column = new int[C];
}
```

}

Comment: You haven't allocated memory for `*row`.

Comment: I thought I did with int **row = new int*[rowCount];

Comment: That allocates memory for `row`. Now all you have is `rowCount` uninitialized pointers.

Comment: Why have you got something called row in readFile and in the constructor? Are they meant to be the same thing?

Comment: Also: your constructor is declared to receive two ints. You pass it **row, which you never initialize, so you get some undefined value for the first parameter.